# Extract HttpError from HttpResponseException

Tags: c#, .net, exception, asp.net-web-api

I would get a HTTPResponseException from a REST service I invoke, in case of an error. I want to get the error message details out of it, so that I can hadle accordingly. How can I extract the error data or innerexception information of the HTTPResponseException returned?

Answer (score 1):

[HttpResponseException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpresponseexception_properties(v=vs.118).aspx) inherits properties from `Exception` so once you have the `HTTPResponseException` object you can simply read the inner exception as below.

```
catch(HttpResponseException e) {
     if (e.InnerException != null)
        Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea about how HttpError can be extracted

Comment: HttpReponseException has a property Response which you can read Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.Response); The URL I posted will show you all the information which the exception provides.